# jQuery PHP Ajax jSon show data into Google Chart

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have jQuery Google Chart(Organization Chart type) from this [Website](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart)

Here is the JS Code:

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages:["orgchart"]});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Manager');
    data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');

    // For each orgchart box, provide the name, manager, and tooltip to show.
    data.addRows([
      [{v:'Mike', f:'Mike<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">President</div>'},
       '', 'The President'],
      [{v:'Jim', f:'Jim<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Vice President</div>'},
       'Mike', 'VP'],
      ['Alice', 'Mike', ''],
      ['Bob', 'Jim', 'Bob Sponge'],
      ['Carol', 'Bob', '']
    ]);

    // Create the chart.
    var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    // Draw the chart, setting the allowHtml option to true for the tooltips.
    chart.draw(data, {allowHtml:true});
  }
```

As We can see the data get from that `data.addRows`.
But now I want to use the data get from PHP, how can I do that?

PHP Code

```
$qItem1 = oci_parse($c1, "SELECT * FROM WA_II_TBL_ITEM1 WHERE EQUIPMENTID_FK = '" . $getEquipmentID . "'");
oci_execute($qItem1);
while($dItem1 = oci_fetch_array($qItem1))
{
    $item1[] = $dItem1['ITEM1NAME'];
    $minQtyItem1[] = $dItem1['MIN_QUANTITY'];

    $qItem2 = oci_parse($c1, "SELECT * FROM WA_II_TBL_ITEM2 WHERE ITEM1ID_FK = '" . $dItem1['ITEM1ID'] . "'");
    oci_execute($qItem2);
    while($dItem2 = oci_fetch_array($qItem2))
    {
        $item2[] = $dItem2['ITEM2NAME'];
        $minQtyItem2[] = $dItem2['MIN_QUANTITY'];
    }
}

$data = array(
"equipmentID"     => $getEquipmentIDQ,
"equipmentName"     => $getEquipmentNameQ,
'item1' => $item1,
'minQtyItem1' => $minQtyItem1,
'item2' => $item2,
'minQtyItem2' => $minQtyItem2,
"equipmentStatus"     => $status
);

echo json_encode($data);
```

I have tried using Ajax jSon function but it didn't work(not show anything)

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: "loadEquipmentTransaction",
    type: "POST",
    data:
    {
        equipmentID: equipmentIDValue
    },
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function (jsonStr)
    {
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried checking the jsonStr object?

Comment: Hi @SumodhS how to do that?

Comment: you can use `console.log(jsonStr);` to print something to the browser console or just `alert(jsonStr)` to view as a message box.

Comment: @HiDayurieDave You can also use chrome to put a breakpoint there and inspect the object